# Is there a way to use aiohttp to make API calls that require aws temporary credentials?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aiohttp

I'm trying to make asynchronous API calls that require aws temporary credentials (aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, and aws_session_token). These refresh every hour.
The aiohttp library has a class, **ClientSession** that has the optional parameter **auth** which takes a tuple. Is there a way to pass aws temporary credentials to auth?

Answer (score 1):

For the `auth` parameter tuple in the `ClientSession` class the [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html) states that

> auth (aiohttp.BasicAuth) – an object that represents HTTP Basic Authorization (optional)

Meaning the values you pass will need to be basic auth values. AWS does not use basic authentication it uses the AWS Sigv4 method to create signed URLs for authentication.

You can either do this signing of the URLs yourself, information and python examples to do this can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) or you can use a library that does this signing for you such as [this one](https://pypi.org/project/aws-request-signer/) or one of the many other ones that are available.

Comment: Can you point me to a working example using requests_aws4auth?

Comment: @Alex where you able to find a solution? I'm trying to find a way pass access_key, secret_key, and token to aiohttp

Comment: I'm also looking for an example on this.