# How do I use aiohttp with requests_aws4auth

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

More recent version of this question with more details: [Using aiohttp with requests_aws4auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077509/using-aiohttp-with-requests-aws4auth)

I have synchronous code that puts files in an AWS bucket that uses requests_aws4auth. I want to make it asynchronous using aiohttp. However, aiohttp seems to only work with basicAuth, and no AWS4auth.

The code that works is:

```
    self.auth = AWS4Auth(access_key, secret_key, 'us-east-1', 's3')
    response = requests.put(
        url,
        auth = self.auth,
        data=content)
```

I want something like:

```
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(url = url, auth=self.auth) as session:
        async with session.put(data=content) as resp:
        
            await session.close()
```

But ClientSession wants a basicAuth tuple...

Comment: Similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68672179/is-there-a-way-to-use-aiohttp-to-make-api-calls-that-require-aws-temporary-crede).  It doesn't look like it's possible, because of the `aiohttp`-way. But, you may find some joy in [aiobotocore](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore), though I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

As for now, aiohttp only supports basic auth. But in aiohttp, setting auth will simply add a header, in the session headers.

Here is the code from the aiohttp sources:

```
def update_auth(self, auth: Optional[BasicAuth], trust_env: bool = False) -> None:
    """Set basic auth."""
    if auth is None:
        auth = self.auth
    if auth is None and trust_env and self.url.host is not None:
        netrc_obj = netrc_from_env()
        with contextlib.suppress(LookupError):
            auth = basicauth_from_netrc(netrc_obj, self.url.host)
    if auth is None:
        return
    if not isinstance(auth, helpers.BasicAuth):
        raise TypeError("BasicAuth() tuple is required instead")
    self.headers[hdrs.AUTHORIZATION] = auth.encode()
```

So as you see in this code, aiohttp, will call method encode from auth object then add the result to headers, with AUTHORIZATION as key.

So you can either bypass all that, and simply add the header yourself, or create a new class that heritates AWS4Auth and add the encode() method.

Comment: Yes, currently just add the header needed manually would be the simplest solution.

Comment: what class is that in? do I add that to the session?

Comment: It complains: TypeError: Cannot serialize non-str key <requests_aws4auth.aws4auth.AWS4Auth object at 0x7f81cf1e3f10>
When I pass that to request, it works fine.